# How to get samba (computer 1) to show up on windows 7 (computer 2) if both are in the same lan?

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, samba

Sorry for the newb factor but I have two computers (one linux, one windows). I followed this directions on [this website](http://www.basicconfig.com/linux_samba_server_setup). And have been able to make it past the last step without any problems:

```
~$ smbclient -L 192.168.1.3
```

However my sambashare isn't showing in my network on Windows 7? Any advice on how I can get it to show up on my pc?

I believe I have properly configured everything in the network admin panel (url:192.168.1.1) by setting my linux machine as a static ip, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small piece of advice, you are going to be better off following the Ubuntu documentation then the Slackware documentation.

On the samba server, check `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

in the `[global]` section , change your workgroup. I think the default windows workgroup is still WORKGROUP

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
```

The guide you linked had you change the name to MYGROUP

See also

[Ubuntu Server Guide Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html)

[Ubuntu wiki Samba Client Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Sometimes the samba drive does not show at all, sometimes after a (long) while.

If you know that your share is up and running, the easy workaround is to type in Explorer in the address line on top (mine shows >Libraries>):

```
\\servername\sharename
```

If your samba is set up correctly, you may be prompted for username, password, etc.
If you want you can let Windows 7 automatically connect the shared drive when you log in. Then your problem is solved.